# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry and pagination missing required attribute

Tags: java, grails

I have this list method in user controller

```
def listUser(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [userInstanceList: User.list(params), userInstanceTotal: User.count()]
}
```

and under **myView.gsp**

```
<g:sortableColumn params="[controller='user']" property="username" title="${message(code: 'user.username.label', default: 'Username')}" />
```

but it gives me an error *java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry*

also the paginate

```
<div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate controller="user" action="listUser" total="${userInstanceTotal}" />
</div>
```

gives a *Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total]* error

though when its under **listUser.gsp** both errors are gone

Answer (score 1):

```
<g:sortableColumn params="[controller='user']" ...>
```

That equals sign should be a colon

```
<g:sortableColumn params="[controller:'user']" ...>
```